# Asp.NET core View component view is not firing $(document).ready()

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, document-ready, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am new to ASP.NET core.
I am loading a different view under components folder using view component based on a condition.

```
<div class="container" id="patientLayout">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("PatientView", new {model = Model})
</div>

 public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(PatientTabViewModel model)
        {
            switch (model.Id)
            {               
                case 3:
                    PatientMessageViewModel msgModel=GetMessagesViewModel(model.PatientId);
                    return await Task.FromResult(View("_messages.cshtml", msgModel));
             }
        }
```

I have a `$(document).ready()` function in `_Messages.cshtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('ready function fired');        
        }
    });
</script>
```

Issue:  This ready function is getting fired for first time only but next time onwards its not getting fired,but breakpoint getting hit at case 3 every time.

Could you please provide some info/solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.Reference :[$( document ).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)